# Web one Click publish - production Protection

Tags: visual-studio-2010, click, publish

How can I protect myself and my colleagues to press on publish production "by accident".
I know I can hide this by right click but I does not want that, I don't want to remove the production publish.

I am looking for a toggle to set it "on" and use it ans set it off again.

Do you know what I mean??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've adopted the practice of only publishing from a single build machine via script. This eliminates the risk and provides and automated method of publishing. Publishing from a developers machine directly is inherently risky.